# Which of the following sets of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Which of the following sets of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}$?
>
> $S_1=\{f|\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 3}f(x)=0\}$, $S_2=\{h|\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 3}h(x)=1\}$, $S_3=\{g|\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 3}g(x)~ \text{exists}\}$
>
> 1. Only $S_1$.
> 2. Only $S_2.$
> 3. $S_1$ and $S_3$ but not $S_2$
> 4. All of the three are vector spaces.

$S_1$ is definitely a vector subspace but $S_2$ is not as it doesn't contain $0$. But I am confused about the $S_3$. As there is no specific limit mentioned, so it means all sorts of limits are possible, including $0$. So I guess $S_3$ is also a vector subspace. That means option 3 is correct.  Is my solution correct? Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

For $S_3$ : Take $g,h \in S_3$.

Then $\lim_{x \to 3} g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 3} h(x)$ both exist.

Now check

1. $\lim_{x \to 3} (g(x)+h(x))=\lim_{x \to 3} g(x)+\lim_{x \to 3} h(x)=\text{exists}.$ This implies that $g+h \in S_3$.
2. let $a \in \Bbb R$ be arbitrary. Then $\lim_{x \to 3} ag(x)=a\lim_{x \to 3} g(x)=\text{exists}$. This implies $ag \in S_3$.

From 1 and 2, $S_3$ is also a vector space.

Note : "Limit exists" means that the limit is finite.